# Current Determination - 12V to 5V (USB Output)

Tags: power, usb, automotive, fuses

I am attempting to determine the current in an automotive installation of a 12V to 5V converter that will supply a USB output. Max output on the 5V side will be 3 Amps.

```
Power = Volts * Current = 5V * 3 Amp = 15 Watts
```

Therefore, does the 12V side have to conform to:

```
15 Watts = 12V * I, solving for I giving, 1.25 Amps.
```

Thus a 2 Amp fuse is sufficient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 12 V input has to supply *at least* 15 W.  Actually it will always be a bit more due to the inefficiency of the converter.

For example, let's say your converter is 90% efficient.  That means to produce 15 W out, it needs (15 W)/90% = 16.7 W in.  For 12 V input, that means it will draw (16.7 W)/(12 V) = 1.4 A.

Note that car power can vary considerably.  The battery may be around 12 V when everything else is off, but is usually held at around 13.6 V when the engine is running.  It can dip to 9 V or less during starting, and there can be 10s of volts of spikes occasionally during operation.

Comment: An overview of those voltage spikes/transients can be found here: http://www.industrologic.com/autotransients.pdf .  As stated there, certain transients can reach even higher voltages (up to 300V for inductive-load switching). Automotive manufacturers define strict reliability requirements for devices using the battery including resistance/resilience to transients.

Answer (score 4):

While I go with @Olin Lathrop's answer (+1), I would like to add this for completeness:

Depending on power (current) range and age of the converter it may contain a linear regulator. Think of this as a big resistor, whose resistance is always automatically adjusted so that an attached device gets its 5V.

In this case, your device may draw a maximum of 3A, but as the regulator is just a resistor, the full 3A are taken from the 12V.

The efficiency is quite bad. While the device draws 3A*5V=15W, the regulator has to dissipate 3A*7V=21W as heat. This is way too much for (smaller sized) voltage converters. Instead, buck converters are used, where power taken from 12V equals power passed to the device, plus ~10-20%. (-> @Olin Lathrop's answer)

But a low power USB port giving not more than let's say 500mA may still use linear regulators, and so sink a maximum current of 500mA from the 12V line. The 3.5W dissipated in this case is still more than the 2.5W used by the device, but 3.5W is not sooo much, and the design is cheaper.

Comment: I've disassembled a few car USB/mobile phone power supplies in the last 3-4 years, and to my great surprise every one of them was switching mode PS. Some were very cheap, some not so, but none had a linear regulator inside. I'm inclined to say that linear regulators are the thing of the past now. Good bye, 7805!

Comment: @Jerz: It's not surprising at all.  The electronics to do the switching is cheaper than any means to get rid of the heat.